# Join 3 tables using Group By MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am trying to build a query that can provide me the desired output using the following 3 tables:

### Table_A

```
|-----------|--------|
|    scui   |  text  |
|    1002   |   abc  |
|    1002   |   def  |
|    1002   |   ghi  |
|-----------|--------|
```

### Table_B

```
|------------|-----------|
|    scui    |    cui    |
|    1002    |    c002   |
|    1003    |    c003   |
|    1004    |    c004   |
|------------|-----------|
```

### Table_C

```
|-----------|------------|------------|
|    cui    |    text    |    scui    |
|    c002   |    123     |            |
|    c002   |    456     |            |
|    c002   |    abc     |    1002    |
|-----------|------------|------------|
```

### Desired Output

```
|------------|------------|
|    scui    |    text    |
|    1002    |    abc     |
|    1002    |    def     |
|    1002    |    ghi     |
|    1002    |    123     |
|    1002    |    456     |
|------------|------------|
```

I tried a couple of options like using `Join` to connect all three tables but using the `Join`, I wasn't able to use Group By for a specific `Join`. The query that I created is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.scui, c.cui, a.text FROM Table_A a 
JOIN
    Table_B b ON (a.scui = b.scui)
JOIN
    Table_C c ON (b.cui = c.cui)
GROUP BY a.scui;
```

After thinking a lot I was wondering I can also use `Table_A` and `Table_C`, and perform a `SELF JOIN`, but not sure if that would be a right option.

Comment: In Table_C scui for first two rows is null? or all three rows have same scui i.e: 1002?

Comment: It is an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to your desired  output seems you need  an union between the first tabel and the others in join

```
SELECT  a.scui,  a.text 
FROM Table_A a 
UNION 
select b.scui, c.text
from Table_B b
INNER JOIN Table_C c on b.cui = c.cui
```

The UNION  clause return distinct result

Answer (score 0):

Using `union` you can get result easily

```
SELECT scui, text 
FROM Table_A
UNION 
SELECT Table_B.scui, Table_C.text
FROM Table_B INNER JOIN Table_C ON TABLE_B.cui = TABLE_C.cui
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table_A
|-----------|--------|
|    scui   |  text  |
|    1002   |   abc  |
|    1002   |   def  |
|    1002   |   ghi  |
|-----------|--------|

Table_B
|------------|-----------|
|    scui    |    cui    |
|    1002    |    c002   |
|    1003    |    c003   |
|    1004    |    c004   |
|------------|-----------|

Table_C
|-----------|------------|------------|
|    cui    |    text    |    scui    |
|    c002   |    123     |            |
|    c002   |    456     |            |
|    c002   |    abc     |    1002    |
|-----------|------------|------------|

Desired Output
|------------|------------|
|    scui    |    text    |
|    1002    |    abc     |
|    1002    |    def     |
|    1002    |    ghi     |
|    1002    |    123     |
|    1002    |    456     |
|------------|------------|
```

We need to use both [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT  A.scui,  A.text 
FROM Table_A as A 
UNION 
SELECT B.scui, C.text
from Table_B as B
JOIN Table_C as C on B.cui = C.cui
```

Result:

[image: query result]